How do you authenticate a call to a logic app (standard) via oAuth2.0?
I'm trying to make a call from Azure API Management to a Logic App (standard) workflow with a manual trigger.  I'd like to authenticate with a token using the system-assigned managed identity for APIM instead of using an SAS.  I've assigned the Logic App Contributor role to APIM's managed identity for the logic app's scope.  I'm trying to use an authentication-managed-identity policy to retrieve the token, but I don't know what the resource should be set to to request the correct scope for the logic app.
I've also tried to configure an app registration in Entra Id with the correct permissions, so that I can use a client credentials flow to get a token for the logic app, but I don't know what permissions the app registration needs for that.  I can retrieve a token, but it doesn't have any notable claims since I'm not providing a scope.
I've found a great deal of information on how to use oAuth2.0 with Logic Apps (consumption), but I can't find anything that relates to Logic Apps (standard).  I've tried applying the information I've found for Logic Apps (consumption), but I suspect that the scope that I need to request in the token call is different.
This specific use case is for calling from APIM to Logic Apps (standard), but I'm interested in any information on how to call Logic Apps (standard) with oAuth2.0 from any client without an SAS.

There is no specific scenario for logic app standard. you configure oauth on top of the logic app (it is just an app service) then grant permission to the APIM identity. from apim you can use this policy in APIM to obtain a token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authentication-managed-identity-policy

In order to call a Standard logic app from APIM, you need to break the Http request URL into 2 parts as illustrated in this blog as direct import is only supported for Consumption logic app for now.
In this case you should be using https://afreeen-la-1.azurewebsites.net:443/api/test/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01 in APIM as shown below.
1st part - https://afreeen-la-1.azurewebsites.net:443/api/

2nd part  - test/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01

Register a new application in Microsoft Entra ID or use an existing app.
Add the given policy in the inbound section of the above created operation.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="{ClientId of the Entra App}" />
    </inbound>
</policies>

Then, navigate to Authentication blade of logic app and add identity provider with the given details.
You can also go for Allow requests from any application option if you don't want to specify the client application id.



Following these steps, I can able to invoke standard logic app in APIM without using SAS.



Is there a way to do this without creating an app registration?  I need to do this for a lot of logic apps, and I'd rather not make clutter in my tenant.

If you are enabling Oauth then you need to use apps.
